# Network calls not happening asynchronously using Kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx

I created a generic function to run a few network calls parallely and then collect their results.

```
fun <T> runAsync(process: () -> T, coroutineScope: CoroutineScope): Deferred<T> {
  return coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO + RequestCoroutineContext() + SecurityCoroutineContext()) {
    process()
  }
}
```

Now I use this method to be used to make network calls and collect their results like this ->

```
runBlocking {
       // async is the same method that is written above
      val job1 = runAsync({ netWorkCallOne(params) }, this)
      val job2 = runAsync({ netWorkCallTwo(params) }, this)
      val job3 = runAsync({ netWorkCallThree(params) }, this)
      val job4 = runAsync({ netWorkCallFour(params) }, this)
      val job5 = runAsync({ netWorkCallFive(params) }, this)
      val job6 = runAsync({ netWorkCallSix(params) }, this)

      someData4 = job5.await()
      someData5 = job6.await()
      someData3 = job4.await()
      someData2 = job3.await()
      someMoreData = job2.await()
      someData = job1.await()
    }
```

I can see in the logs that no two calls are happening sequentially waiting for one network call to finish and then the next call starts.
What can I change here to make it run parallely?

Comment: I created a MRE here: https://pastebin.com/Q0dFyUUT which works as expected. I suspect is has something to do with your `RequestCoroutineContext() + SecurityCoroutineContext()`. Try logging `Thread.currentThread().name` to see if the coroutines actually run on separate threads.